# Cannot get insides of the element from other app

Tags: c#, windows, ui-automation

I want to find specific button with text(find it by text) and press it.
I'm trying to get insides from 'group'('группа' on screanshot) element of a teleramm desctop app, i know there is defenetly list of buttons there, but i cant find anything with UIA and inspect.exe. I tried both raw automtaion dll and nuget UIAComWrapper.
SendMessage(to get text) and EnumChildWindows didn't help me as well, as SendMessage enum does not return other handles inside of app.

```
AutomationElementCollection automation_element_collection = group_element.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition); //empty collection
AutomationElement automation_element_collection = group_element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition); //returns null
            
TreeWalker raw_view_walker = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker;
AutomationElement automation_element = raw_view_walker.GetFirstChild(group_element); //returns null
```

What am i doing wrong and may there be any other projects to help me with this?

[screanshot from inspector.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqg0h.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telegram Desktop app just doesn't support accessibility features like UIA for ages, look at the [Github ticket](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/476). Formally, it works, but on a really basic level - there is no option to retrieve the message history textual content, group and contact names, etc.

So, until any of those implemented, there is just no way to programmatically traverse the UI elements. But if you really need it, you could look at OCR.